# Can't add or edit menu item

Tags: 6

Something was happened to my site, so now I can't add or edit items in all my menus: I see just buttons 'Save', 'Cancel'. Where can I find solution of this problem, what can be a reason of this? I use Drupal 6.26
[image: Editing menu item]
[image: Try to add menu item]

Comment: What happen if you switch theme? did you still can't see it?

Comment: I'd suggest running any necessary database updates (/update.php), then clearing all caches. This may resolve your problem